# A simple estimate (Theorem 8.6) Haim Brezis' book $\|Pu\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R})}\leq 2 \|u\|_{L^p(I)}$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces

I am trying to prove a very simple estimate for extensions (Theorem 8.6) from the Brezis, i.e.,

$\|Pu\|_{L^{p}(\mathbb{R})} \leq 2 \|u\|_{L^{p}(I)}$

where $I = (0,\infty)$ and

$(Pu) (x)= \begin{bmatrix} u(x)\quad \text{for} \; x\geq 0,  \\u(-x) \quad \text{for} \; x<0\end{bmatrix}$

Likewise, the estimate: if $u^* = (Pu) \in W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R})$ then $\|Pu\|_{W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R})} \leq 2 \|u\|_{W^{1,p}(I)}$.

If I use the definition, I end up with an equality while it is an inequality in the proof.

Using the definition,

$\|Pu\|_{L^{p}(\mathbb{R})}^p=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|Pu|^p dx = \int_{-\infty}^{0}|u(-x)|^pdx + \int_{0}^{\infty}|u(x)|^p dx $.

Change of variables and reversing the order of integration,

$\|Pu\|_{L^{p}(\mathbb{R})}^p = \int_{0}^{\infty}|u(y)|^p dy + \int_{0}^{\infty}|u(x)|^p dx ,$

Where I used $y=-x$ and reversed the order of integration in the first integral. Finally, I get

$\|Pu\|_{L^{p}(\mathbb{R})}^p = 2\int_{0}^{\infty}|u(x)|^p dx = 2\|u\|_{L^p(I)}^p.$

Can someone suggest where I am making the mistake, as it is trivial but I am kinda stuck..... Thanks in advance.

Comment: looks correct... why do you think it's wrong ?

Comment: @Surb In the book it states as an inequality, i.e., $\|Pu\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R})}\leq 2 \|u\|_{L^p(I)}$ which leads to the question, what I am overlooking or if I am doing something wrong here?

Comment: well, since $P(u)(x)=u(\pm x)$n it completely make sense to have the, equality...

Comment: After taking the $p$th root you will get $$\|Pu\|_p=2^{1/p}\|u\|_p\le 2\|u\|_p$$